# Why we always persist the owning side of relationship in JPA ? why don't we persist the other side of relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to learning JPA. while going through the one-to-many relation in JPA, I have noticed one thing that they always persit the owning side (the side which contains the foreign key). For example if we have two entities (order and orderitems) and we have following code for unidirectional relation between order and order items.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
 
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = “fk_order”)
    private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
 
    …
}
```

Now when ever we have to persist order. we need to save order item to database like following

```
Order o = em.find(Order.class, 1L);
 
OrderItem i = new OrderItem();
 
o.getItems().add(i);
 
em.persist(i);
```

Now my questions is that should be it like we fetch the order from the database or creater new order and add the order items to its orderitmeslist and then save this order to database instead of saving orderitems like follwing

```
Order o = em.find(Order.class, 1L);
 
OrderItem i = new OrderItem();
 
o.getItems().add(i);
 
em.persist(o);
```

and it should automatically save the orderitem to orderitem table as these two have one-to-many relation.

Why we always need to persist the owning side of relation, like here we are always persisting the orderitems to database either we are using bidirectional or unidirectional approach, why we always need to save the owning side (orderitem) ? why don't we just add the order items to the ordertiermslist of order entity and just persist the other side of relation (order) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for cascading operations and jpa actually support this. U need CascadeType.PERSIST (or CascadeType.ALL if you need).

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // or CascadeType.ALL
@JoinColumn(name = “fk_order”)
private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
```

After persisting your "Order" you will also save items

Here you can read more about cascade types: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Btw:
Avoid naming entities and columns with sql keywords like: order, from etc. It may make some conflicts during hibernate query generation (I lost a lot of time for bugs like that :D).

`When you map a many-to-many association, you should use a Set instead of a List....`:

In many-to-many relation you need to have additional association table.

Here is an exampel to visualize:
[image]

In this case both sides (customer and product) will have records sales from their collections (sales).

When one side has a list and will try to remove it will delete all of the records and then reinsert all that should be in db (cuz list may keep duplicates).

```sql
-- delete existing
delete from customer
where customer_id = ?

-- n inserts
insert into sales(col1, col2, ...)
values(val1, val2, ...)
```

In case when you will use set during removing item you will do something like:

```sql
delete from customer
where customer_id = ? and product_id = ?
```

Here u can read more: Here is a pretty good article: https://dzone.com/articles/why-set-is-better-than-list-in-manytomany

Comment: can you also expalin this statement "When you map a many-to-many association, you should use a Set instead of a List as the attribute type. Otherwise, Hibernate will take a very inefficient approach to remove entities from the association. It will remove all records from the association table and re-insert the remaining ones. You can avoid that by using a Set instead of a List as the attribute type."
i read it but don't know the reason for it. kindly explain with example

Comment: Ye, look edit <comment too short :D>